# Elastic Search with Searckiq Incorrect Scoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a model Grave, where I want to query on name with query being "Krogness"

I notice one thing, the results being returned are having same scores.
I reduced the no of shards to 1 as mentioned in the documentation (No luck).
I even disabled misspellings (No luck)

I have attached the detailed mapping and desc below.

**Model**

```
searchkick word_middle: %i[name plot_number], callbacks: :async, settings: {number_of_shards: 1}
```

**Model Searchkick Options**

```
{:word_middle=>[:name, :plot_number],
:callbacks=>:async,
:settings=>{:number_of_shards=>1},
:_type=>
#<Proc:0x00007f53349fcf98@/home/akshayparekh/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bundler/gems/searchkick-bcd6edc872f2/lib/searchkick/model.rb:17 (lambda)>,
:class_name=>"Grave"}
```

**Search Options**

```
{:fields=>["name^10", "plot_number"],
:where=>{:grave_status=>[:accepted, :claimed], :hidden=>false},
:operator=>:or,
:page=>"1",
:per_page=>30,
:misspellings=>false,
:debug=>true}
```

**Query**

```
curl http://localhost:9200/graves_development/_search?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"bool":{"should":[{"dis_max":{"queries":[{"match":{"name.analyzed":{"query":"Krogness","boost":100.0,"operator":"or","analyzer":"searchkick_search"}}},{"match":{"name.analyzed":{"query":"Krogness","boost":100.0,"operator":"or","analyzer":"searchkick_search2"}}}]}},{"dis_max":{"queries":[{"match":{"plot_number.analyzed":{"query":"Krogness","boost":10,"operator":"or","analyzer":"searchkick_search"}}},{"match":{"plot_number.analyzed":{"query":"Krogness","boost":10,"operator":"or","analyzer":"searchkick_search2"}}}]}}]}},"filter":[{"terms":{"grave_status":["accepted","claimed"]}},{"term":{"hidden":{"value":false}}}]}},"timeout":"11s","_source":false,"size":30}'
```

**Results**

```
{
"took": 2,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 1,
"successful": 1,
"skipped": 0,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": {
"value": 2,
"relation": "eq"
},
"max_score": 1275.969,
"hits": [
{
"_index": "graves_development_20210926173013383",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "264729",
"_score": 1275.969
},
{
"_index": "graves_development_20210926173013383",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "264730",
"_score": 1275.969
}
]
}
}
```

I have 2 records to reproduce this issue.

```
Test Krogness
Test Krog
```

Both of them have the same score when I search Krogness

Searchkick version: 4.6.1
Elasticsearch version: 7.14.1

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Usually it makes sense for names *not* to be stemmed (and "Krog" should not be returned altogether). If you really do need them stemmed, you should have subfields like this in your ES mapping:

```
"name": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
    "analyzed": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "searchkick_word_middle_index"},
    "lowercase": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "standard"},
    "raw": {"type": "keyword"},
  }
}
```

Then at the search phase you'll have:

```
["name.raw^100", "name.lowercase^50", "name.analyzed^100", ...]
```

This way you'll have "more precise" matches scored higher.

To make searchkick apply these mappings for you you'll need something like this:

```
searchkick merge_mappings: true, mappings: {{
  properties: {
    name: {
      type: "text"
      fields: {...}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above steps, it now does not fetch any records related to Krogness at all. It fetches records like Krogdal

Comment: I'm not sure which analyzer does searchkick use by default. You can try to get mapping (`curl http://localhost:9200/graves_development/_mapping`) of the default configuration (with no custom mappings in your code) and replace "searchkick_word_middle_index" with that. If it still doesn't work please post the mapping here.